# Getting 500 error in request due to wrong date format

Tags: android, android-studio, android-calendar, android-datepicker, android-json

I am getting 500 server error due to wrong date format which is taken via Datepicker dialog.It compiles into : "**refer log below in dob as key"** instead of **17/11/2011**.How can it be resolved.
This is my code in OnCreate:

```
final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        int month=monthOfYear+1;
        dob.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+month+"/"+year);
    }
};

findViewById(R.id.prof_set_dob).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        new DatePickerDialog(SignupActivity.this, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the log:

```
02-06 15:58:38.842 18576-18576/finlit.finlit E/Ff:  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ {"name":"quack","email":"shubhamsaini990@gmail.com","gender":"M","monthly_salary":"2300000","mobile_no":"6978090946","password":"test","dob":"17\/11\/2011"}
```

02-06 15:58:40.276 18576-20911/finlit.finlit E/Volley: [3488] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500

Comment: both are same 17/11/2011 instead of 17/11/2011? then what is the problem.

Comment: your date is correct. check api with POSTMAN

Comment: I'm sorry.I'll edit that. Its actually coming 17\/11\/2011 instead of normal one.

Comment: thats right. Its escape character. It is same as 17/11/2011

Comment: Yeah that escape character is hardcoded as it is in json POST and the api is unable to recognize it.

Comment: have you tried with postman?

Comment: its working in postman when proper date is there without escape chars

Comment: I am pretty sure, what you have to fix is not your android code, but your api.